# Execute script inside HTTP sampler

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I have a following scenario to execute.

1. Upload a file using HTTP sampler
2. During the upload shut down the server using JSR223 sampler

Unfortunately I cannot do it as two separate threads, both samplers have to go into single Thread Group.

The best way to do it would be to trigger the sampler manually from code, but is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are already planning to use JSR223 sampler, why do not you plan to combine these requests - like AJAX requests within 1 sampler?

The below site has very nice information on making AJAX requests using JSR223 sampler.
https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter

So, in that way - first you make a request to upload a file & meantime you also make another request to shutdown the server.